# Mismatch Error in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel Vba and was wondering if anyone could help me figure out how to effectively write this code.

I am trying to compare values using Else-if statements but I keep receiving a Mismatch error when I run the macro. This is what I have so far:

```
Dim score1 As Variant, result1 As Variant

 score1 = Range("B24").value
 Sheets("Answers").Range("P1") = VarType(score1)

If VarType(score1) = 0 Then
        result1 = "Error"
        msg1 = " INPUT A VALUE"
    ElseIf score1 > (((Range("I24").value - Range("H24").value) * 0.2) + ((Range("H24").value + Range("I24").value) / 2)) Then
        result1 = score1
        msg1 = " Adjust the Left Flank of fH_Beta"
    ElseIf score1 < (((Range("I24").value - Range("H24").value) * 0.2) - ((Range("H24").value + Range("I24").value) / 2)) Then
        result1 = score1
        msg1 = " Adjust the Left Flank of fH_Beta"
    Else
        result1 = "N/A"
        msg1 = " No action required"
End If

 Sheets("Answers").Range("F11").value = result1
```

The error started appearing when I changed the two Elseif lines from > 2.3 and <-7.7 to the formulas shown in the code.  I need to write these formulas because the values (2.3 & -7.7) may change depending on the application.

By the way, the first line (the IF line) is supposed to save an error message if the cell is left empty.  I believe the error has something to do with me defining the variables as type "Double" but I cannot find a way to fix it (I also tried saving the varialbes As String and changed each .value to .Text).

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks...

****Update: The code above is now the current code I have.  The formula in this code is supposed to take values in I24 and H24 (-7.7 & 2.3) and give an upper tolerance of -0.7 (line with the + in it) and a lower tolerance of -4.7 (line with a - in it) and use these tolerances to evaluate the user's input (B24).

If the cell is left blank, the code runs the First IF line and returns a msg1 value of "INPUT A VALUE".  If the user inputs a number out of tolerance the code should give a msg1 value of "Adjust the Left Flank of fH_Beta".  If neither of these conditions are met, the input should be within tolerance and the msg1 value should be "No action required".

My problem is, no matter what value I put into B24 (even an in-tolerance value), I get a msg1 value of "Adjust the Left Flank of fH_Beta" and I do not know why.  If I need to clear things up further please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use range references in VBA the same way you do in formulas. You need: `Range("I24").Value - Range("H24").Value` rather than `I24 - H24` for example.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I typed all of my values as you stated and changed my variables to variants as Bathsheba said and my code runs without error now.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't finish.  The code still does not work correctly, though (i.e. I will type a number into B24 that will fall in between values of 2.3 and -7.7 (which should default to the Else line of the code) but my output is still returning the msg1 statement found under the Elseif lines.

Comment: Please update the question to reflect the revised code, as well as what is currently happening that shouldn't, and what should happen. (it may help to give examples of the values in question)

Comment: Ok Rory, I updated the question to its current state.  If this doesn't help clarify please let me know.

Comment: It's a logic issue. **Any** value will be *either* lower than the top threshold or higher than the low threshold. Your "No action required" should test for the value being **both** greater than the low **and** lower than the high, and the Else part should return the adjustment message. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, that was a careless error on my part.  I appreciate you pointing that out, everything should work now. Thanks!!

Comment: Wait, sorry but unless I am still overlooking something it still does not make sense.  To simplify I am going to assign arbitrary values to the lower and upper tolerances (say 0 and 5, respectively).  The first statements checks to see IF the value is greater than 5.  The second should check to see IF the input is less than 0.  So say the input is 3; sense this number falls into neither of those ranges, the code should go to the ELSE line.  That is the way I have it set up.

Comment: Then I suspect your limit values aren't what you think. What are the actual values in each of the three cells? (please make sure you get the correct cells for each value!)

Comment: H24 = -7.7 and I24 = 2.3.  The formulas above should convert these numbers into a lower tolerance of -4.7 and an upper of -0.7.  I have been useing -3.0 as an arbitrary test value (because it falls within tolerance and should not be adjusted) but the code still returns the "adjustment needed" message.  I have checked my math a couple of times but do not find any mistakes and that is why I figured that I had coded something wrong.

Comment: Your "lower" tolerance is 4.7 not -4.7 using your code...

Comment: Haha, I had to write it out but I realize that now.  Hopefully that will fix all of my problems. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `score` is a `double` (i.e. a number), it makes no sense to compare it with a blank string.

`If score1 = ""` makes no sense. It will give you a type mismatch error.

An alternative is to use a `variant` for `score`. A variant can exist as a string, or a number, amongst other types. You can then use the `Vartype` function to check what's inside the variant.

Comment: Thanks for responding Bathsheba.  I am working on a way to incorporate Vartype into my code now.